# Rxjs: use values of observables in function that return promise/observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

So i have chained functions that return Promise, and in arguments i need to use values of observables. look at the descriptions in the code to understand. I think i should use some of rxjs operators to write this code in reactive programming way? but i don't now how to do it exactly, which of them to use.

```
interface User {
  email: string;
  conversations: string[] | FieldValue;
  userId: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ConversationsClientService {
  getUserByEmail(email: string): Observable<any> {
    // should return Observable<User[]> but this function return type is Observable<unknown[]> and i can't use this type, but thats not the main issue
    return this.firestore
      .collection('users', (ref) => ref.where('email', '==', email))
      .valueChanges();
  }

  startNewConversation(
    currentUserCredential: Observable<firebase.auth.UserCredential>, //that comes from ngrx selector
    email: string
  ): Promise<void> {
    //or return observable by wrapping promise with from() operator
    return this.firestore
      .doc<User>(
        'users/' + 'there should be .user.uid field of value of observable currentUserCredential'
      )
      .update({
        conversations: arrayUnion(
          'there should be [0].userId field of value of observable getUserByEmail(email)'
        ),
      });
  }

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {}
}
```

Comment: Can you explain bit more about your use-case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise to go with the `from` operator instead of a Promise and model the whole operation as a RxJs stream.

One Option would be:

```js
  startNewConversation(
    currentUserCredential: Observable<firebase.auth.UserCredential>, //that comes from ngrx selector
    email: string
  ): Promise<void> {
    /* combineLatest will emit an array with the most recent emitted values of the combined observables */
    return combineLatest([currentUserCredential, this.getUserByEmail(email)]).pipe(
      switchMap((currentUserAndUserByEmail) => {
        return from(this.firestore
          .doc<User>(
            'users/' + currentUserAndUserByEmail[0].user.uid,
          )
          .update({
            conversations: arrayUnion(
              currentUserAndUserByEmail[1][0].userId
            ),
          }))
      } )
    )
  }
```